# How do PostgreeSQL functions return multiple columns and rows to a Java application?

Tags: java, postgresql, stored-procedures

I am trying to get 3 fields from 1 table using a function and I am getting errors:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sp_search_test_ui_test_prog_revision(dev TEXT)
RETURNS table (dev_op_test_id BIGINT, test_program_name TEXT, test_program_revision TEXT) 
AS $$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY
    SELECT dev_op_test_id, test_program_name, test_program_revision
    FROM dev_op_test
    WHERE device = dev
    ORDER BY dev_op_test_id;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The JAVA code is below: (device is a String passed to this method) Is this where the error is?

```
    // Get unique devices from dev_op_test
    String sql = " SELECT sp_search_test_ui_test_prog_revision(" + device + ") ";
    PreparedStatement statement = pgConn.prepareStatement(sql);

    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();

    // Clear from previous run
    cboTestProgDev.getItems().clear();

    while (rs.next()) {
        TestProgRev tpr = new TestProgRev();
        tpr.setDevOpTestId(rs.getLong(1));
        tpr.setTestProgramName(rs.getString(2));
        tpr.setTestProgramRevision(rs.getString(3));
        testProgs.add(tpr);
        cboTestProgDev.getItems().add(tpr.toString());
    }
```

And this is the error I keep getting. Notice it's telling me the column doesn't exist, which is true because that is a value not a column name. Any ideas??? I know it may be something simple, I just can't seem to ding the anwser.
[image]

Comment: As I posted in your last post, see http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/callproc.html - If you think that the `postgresql` site is wrong, then tell us why.

Answer (score 2):

The query you are sending is

```sql
SELECT sp_search_test_ui_test_prog_revision(mnf0306aa)
```

Do you notice the missing single quotes around the string? That is why PostgreSQL interprets it as a column name and complains that the column does not exist.

Composing queries with string concatenation is dangerous, it exposes you to the dangers of SQL injection. If `device` contains a single quote, your statement would cause an error or worse – a skilled attacker could do anything with your database.

Use the power of prepared statements to avoid that danger:

```java
java.sql.PreparedStatement statement =
    pgConn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM sp_search_test_ui_test_prog_revision(?)";
statement.setString(1, device);
java.sql.ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Totally spaced the single quotes for many hours!!! Also, implemented this properly as you suggested! I knew it was something simple I was missing. Thanks again! Peace...

Comment: @ChristopherJ.Reynolds: as that is a set returning function, you should also use it like a table `select * from sp_search_test_ui_test_prog_revision(?)`

Comment: I did just that. Works great! Thanks!